# Как правильно оформить прямую речь, которая так похожа на непрямую?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Действующие лица: он - давний художник, она - недавно дипломированный искусствовед.

> Я стала ему по-настоящему полезна – могу привести пример
>   художествености, обнаружить нужную ассоциацию, обратить его внимание
>   на важную деталь. И как я люблю ему повторять: у меня есть
>   документально подтвержденное право высказывать тебе свою критику.

(Про "пример художественности", смутивший меня, автору уже отправлен запрос.)

Проблема в последнем предложении.

Просто запятую после "и"?

*И, как я люблю ему повторять: у меня есть документально подтверждённое право высказывать тебе свою критику.*

Так?

Comment: Если бы я был причастен к какой-нибудь реформе пунктуации, первым делом ввёл бы правило отбрасывания любых запятых после "и" - это всегда вопиюще противоречит интонации (кроме случаев письменной передачи сбивчиво произнесённого тоста). Здесь злостно оставил бы как есть.

Answer (score 2):

Проблему вижу, но как решать не знаю. Одной запятой тут не отделаешься.
По-хорошему её тут-то вообще не надо, коли вы используете двоеточие в продолжении фразы. Проблема возникает из-за длинного предложения, не сразу видно, что предложение не восклицательное ("И как же я люблю ему повторять!").

Но если отделять запятой, то получается, что она отделяет вообще всю фразу от союза, поскольку двоеточие "не останавливает" обособление - ни зрительно, ни синтаксически.

Я думаю, единственный выход - слегка изменить синтаксические взаимоотношения и рассматривать "как я люблю повторять" как вводное. Смысла это абсолютно не изменит.

***И, как я люблю ему повторять, у меня есть документально подтвержденное право высказывать тебе свою критику.***

Думаю, что автор не будет возражать, видно, что до таких глубоких рассуждений о смысле запятой он не поднимается.

*Эдакий каламбур получился, а-ля "зияющие высоты", даже жалко править.)))*

Comment: Спасибо! *П р о с т о*  две запятые не пришли мне в голову! 8-(

Comment: При такой пунктуации нужно заменять "тебе" на "ему" (видимо, обращено к тому, кому повторяют). И это отказ от борьбы за двоеточие.

Comment: @Alex_ander Да ну что вы. Совсем не к тому, а к читателю. Но это в любом случае условный пример, показывающий, с каким именно восклицательным предложением ***можно спутать*** по началу фразы. Будь она покороче, вообще бы не было проблемы.

Comment: Замечательно решает проблему этот вариант с двумя запятыми. Но "тебе" просто недопустимо, на мой взгляд. Можно заменить его на "ему". Но зачем оно нужно здесь вообще? Есть  документально подтвержденное право высказывать критику!  Ведь в документе не написано: право высказывать критику имярек.

Comment: @М_Г *Ведь в документе не написано* да почему? Скорее всего речь идет вообще не о документе (хотел бы я на такой документ посмотреть!), а о каких-то вещах, косвенно подтвердающих это право. Может, это свидетельство о рождении общего ребенка... Или фотография забора с надписью "Маша+Петя=Любовь к искусству"... Вернее всего, конечно, речь идет о дипломе искусствоведа. Критику можно высказывать всем, но далеко не всем она документально подтверждена, как в данном случае.

Comment: *"но далеко не всем она документально подтверждена, как в данном случае"* - смысл этой фразы совсем не понял, извините. По-моему, из контекста ясно. Раз она - недавно дипломированный искусствовед, то считает, что диплом подтверждает ее право высказывать критику. "Тебе", "ему" - лишние слова.

Comment: @М_Г *Право высказывать критику всем есть, но документально подтверждено он далеко не всем* - так понятнее? *По-моему, из контекста ясно* - вам даже из моей фразы это не ясно, а что хотел сказать говорящий, вы уже поняли?!

Comment: Допустим, Вы свою мысль выразили недостаточо ясно, в отличие от автора. Такое возможно? Формально, вы написали, что право ("он" - описка?) высказывать критику "подтверждено не всем" (т.е. не все имеют подтвержденное право высказывать критику), а  хотели сказать, полагаю, что подтверждено право высказывать критику, но "высказывать не всем". Не так ли?